# Необъявленный идентификатор

Tags: delphi

Подскажите, почему пишет, что необъявленный идентификатор, ведь я всё объявил?

```
var    
   n,m:integer;   
   massivCHisel : array [ n,m ] of integer;
```

Ошибку выдаёт в массиве `"array [ n,m ]"`.

Comment: Требуются константы, а не переменные.

Comment: что другое?

Comment: @Igor_bogun ну, вот вы пытаетесь указать заранее неизвестные значения. Это раз. Второе: обратите, пожалуйста, внимание на то, какую именно ошибку вам пишет компилятор. Ответьте на вопрос, что такое n и m? Являются ли они константами? Что указывается в квадратных скобках при объявлении переменной массива?

Answer (score 6):

Дело тут вот в чем. В отличие от Си-подобных языков в pascal/delphi объявление массива подразумевает указание не размера массива, а начального и конечного индексов. 
То есть если вам нужен двумерный массив размером n х m то объявлять его следует так:

```
massivCHisel : array [1..n, 1..m] of integer;
```

если же вы хотели создать одномерный массив с индексами от n  до m, то так:

```
    massivCHisel : array [n..m] of integer;
```

Но и это еще не все. Подобное объявление массива предполагает, что значения его индексов известно на этапе компиляции, то есть вышеприведенные записи по-прежнему не будут верными, поскольку m и n являются не константами, а переменными. Чтобы пример компилировался, вам нужно сделать что-то наподобие:

```
const n = 5;
      m = 6;
var massivCHisel : array [1..n, 1..m] of integer;
```

Если же вас интересует иименно возможность задания границ массива с помощью переменных, то вам имеет смысл посмотреть в сторону динамических массивов

Comment: Действительно, что-то я поторопился со своим комментарием.

Comment: Просто дополню - Не скажу за паскаль, а в Делфи вполне себе можно создавать массивы размером с перечисление или булевый тип. `array[TFonstStyle, Boolean] of`